# Formula needed please

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have many sheets to update where I find if I have this formula, it will cut my time down by not having to enter constant data (being 1). I need Col B1 to have a 1 if Col A1 is NOT empty. (If column A is empty, nothing will appear in B1

I've tried formulas, but I'm fairly new at formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),,1)
```

If you want to apply it to the whole column `B`, you can wrap it in `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A:A),,1))
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! You just saved me having to enter 1 on 15 more spreadsheets a day! (When it's a quiet day)

Comment: @KiwiAnne Happy to hear that it worked.  Could you mark the question as answered, please.